# How can I color a cell where I know the row index and field name in ag-grid?

Tags: ag-grid-angular

[image]
let,
row index = 5 & field = 'age'
Now, how can color the cell which have row = 5 & field = 'age' in ag-grid?  I have tried the last two days but failed to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have an array of objects containing row index and field names:

```
rowIndexes = [ 
  { row: 3, field: ['age']}, 
  { row: 5, field: ['name']}, 
  { row: 10, field: ['name', 'salary'] }
];
```

Add `cellStyle` property to each columnDef:

```
{
  headerName: 'Name',
  field: 'name',
  cellStyle: (params) => {
    let rowIndex = params.node.rowIndex;
    if (this.isColoredCell(rowIndex, 'name'))
      return { backgroundColor: 'red' }
    return null;
  }
}
...
...
```

And add your logic to `isColoredCell` method:

```
isColoredCell(rowIndex: number, field: string): boolean {
  let indexes = this.rowIndexes.filter(item => item.row == rowIndex);
  if (indexes.length > 0) {
    let fields = indexes[0].field;
    if (fields.indexOf(field) > -1) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Hope you can color your cells this way.